# Understanding the way that OneNote for iOS (iPad) uses Bing Images

Tags: ios, ipad, bing, onenote

I am trying to set up an iPad with no access to Bing. I have a domain blocker which prevents access to Bing in a web browser on the iPad, but Bing Images is still accessible in the OneNote App if I click on "Online Images." I have provided a photo. [Online Pictures button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGvEv.jpg) I used the "inspect element" on my desktop version of OneNote to see if I could find a url in the code, but nothing works.

Would anyone know how to find the link that OneNote uses to get photos from Bing images so I may disable it?

Comment: At the end of the day you can't, OneNote can simply choose to now use not-bing.com which just forwards everything to bing.com. And why do you care in the first place?

Comment: It's probably using some office 365 web service. You probably can't block it without blocking office 365